# Game adding to JFrame work not correctly

Tags: java, button, jframe

I have a problem with JFrame becouse if I add code to button in JFrame and then i start game my mowing ball is not working and game start in the end with result you lost. Is there possibility to slower the start of application ??´

This is only code which i want to add to JFrame button.

```
    Ball new = new Ball("BallGame"); 
    new.getName();
    new.writeToFile();
    new.setSize(400, 600);
    new.setVisible(true); 
    new.move( );
```

Comment: And that compiles?

Comment: This shouldnt even compile if your variable is named `new`